# $pd(M) \leq n$ implies $\ker(P_n \to P_{n-1})$ projective

Tags: homological-algebra, projective-module

Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module with $A$ Noetherian. Suppose $pd(M) \leq n$. Then given any projective resolution
$$\ldots \to P_n \to P_{n-1} \to \ldots \to P_0 \to M \to 0$$
why is the kernel of $P_n \to P_{n-1}$ projective? I can see this to be true if $n=1$. However, for the general induction I can't seem to be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we can show that the kernel $K$ of $P_{n-1} \to P_{n-2}$ is projective. Consider any projective resolution $Q_\bullet \to K \to 0$. Then we have the following resolution of $M$:

> $\dots \to Q_m \to \dots \to Q_0 \to P_{n-1} \to \dots \to P_0 \to M \to 0$.

Using this resolution we can compute $\operatorname{Ext}^1_A(K,N) = \operatorname{Ext}^{n+1}_A(M,N) = 0$ for any $A$-module $N$. Because of this the functor $\operatorname{Hom}_A(K,-)$ is exact, which is equivalent to $K$ being projective.

Comment: I think that considering $Q_{\bullet}$ is not necessary at all.

Comment: @user26857: Yes, because $P_\bullet$ is already a resolution we can take $Q_i := P_{n+i}$. But my argumentation also applies if only $P_0, \dots, P_{n-1}$ are given. Maybe this is worth mentioning?

Comment: As you know, the equality of Exts follows by splitting $P_{\bullet}$ in short exact sequences, so there is no need to extend it beyond $K$. On the other side, still remain to prove that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_A(K,N) = \operatorname{Ext}^{n+1}_A(M,N)$ implies $K$ projective.

Comment: @Dune Is what I am saying true then? Because your answer doesn't fit what I am asking for.

Comment: @Lynn16: Yes it is also true by the same argument (replacing $\operatorname{Ext}^{n+1}(M,N)$ by $\operatorname{Ext}^{n+2}(M,N)$). The statement I proved is stronger since it is actually equivalent to $\mathrm{pd}(M) \leq n$. That is why I thought you accidentally wrote $P_n \to P_{n-1}$ instead of $P_{n-1} \to P_{n-2}$.